# API Controllers scope definition

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I dont see any documentation or best practice on how granular we can/should define the controllers in a webapi project. Ive seen that the template from visual studio has AccountController which has endpoints for login, logout, register, etc. Is it a good practice to have all in a single controller or is it fine to have a LoginController, SignUpController, etc.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure why this was closed or set on hold as it was a valid question. I wanted to know the experience of other people as I couldn't find any references or guidelines on how granular I can go.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a good practice to have all in a single controller or is it
>   fine to have a LoginController, SignUpController, etc.

I really depends on your domain and other factors, such as the size of the application.  As a general best practice, if you can, keep your controllers granular.  More importantly, keep the controllers' methods very lean - little or no business or data access logic.  These approaches will facilitate testing an easier maintenance.  Think "Single Responsibility Principal".

Comment: thanks for the comment and share your thoughts!